# BitLocker not accepting correct recovery keys

Tags: windows-10, ssd, bitlocker, disk-encryption, secure-boot

As a test before upgrading to Windows 10 20H2, I disabled Secure Boot and rebooted. I was shown a BitLocker Recovery screen and prompted for the recovery keys. I tried both keys I was given (there are two encrypted drives) but got a message saying `"The recovery key is incorrect"`for each one. The recovery keys are definitely correct. Why can I not access the drives with the correct keys? With Secure Boot on, the laptop boots fine. I don't know if it's relevant but I recently upgraded my SSD drive to a larger drive and re-encrypted it. Would that affect the BitLocker keys?

Answer (score 2):

The original BitLocker Recovery keys were no longer valid. When I checked the settings, the Recovery Keys were different. I assume that when I re-encrypted the new SSD, a new set of Recovery Keys was generated. I wasn't aware of that so I was trying to use the old keys. When I saved the new keys and disabled Secure Boot, they worked.